# Fullpage.js: Change page title based on current section

Tags: jquery, fullpage.js, titlebar, sections, page-title

As the Title of this post already says, how to change the page title based on the the current section in [Fullpage.js?](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fullpage.js has an event onLeave.

```
 onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction){ 
     switch(nextIndex) {
         case 1:
             document.title = "Index";
             break;
         //etc
     }
 },
```

Maybe something like this will do

Comment: PERFECT. Thank you, or in mr. Den Ouden his language: Hartelijk dank! (Nederlanders onder elkaar)

Comment: Geen probleem haha. Toevallig dat ik  zelf laatst met deze plugin aan het testen was